# excel bulk update all array formulas in the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In my worksheet, I have some hundreds of UNIQUE formulas (simple and array). Some of the cells contain array formulas and some simple ones.
I had to bulk edit (find&replace) some characters in all formulas. I exported them as text to notepad++ and did the replacement job and brought them back and pasted back on the worksheet. 
When I press 'calculate the sheet' or alt + ctrl +f9, it doesn't update the array formulas. 
Is there any way to update (refresh) all of the formulas? or should I go one by one and press ctrl+shift+enter? which is not feasible at all given the number of cells that I have.
How can I do it with a vba?
thanks

Comment: I don't know of any way to commit multiple formulas en masse with CSE. Perhaps it's possible with VBA. What I am quite interested in is that you've managed to create a sheet with "hundreds" of "unique" array formulas! That's some sheet! Is there really nothing which connects any of these which can be used as a basis for array-entering just one of a connected group and then copying to other cells to produce the rest?

Comment: actually, in my question I just put a very low estimate of the number of formulas, total number of the unique formula's is more than thousands, most of them array. I had to bulk edit some characters and column names in all. that is why i moved them to an editor. now I am stuck with nonfunctional array formulas. There is almost no connection between the formulas. the number of parameters in each formula is different and dont follow any distinct trend.

Comment: Couldn't you have use the Replace functionality in Excel?

Comment: no, because i was replacing and adding iferror function to the beginning of some of the functions, then i got an error that the formula is not complete, and that is right, because i had to put the ending of iferror formula to the end of the formulas. So i had to bypass this by doing it outside excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a routine like this - it may take a while to recalculate at the end by the sound of it!

```
Sub AddErrorHandler()
    Dim rngFormulas           As Range
    Dim rngCell               As Range
    Dim lngCalcMode           As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngFormulas = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngFormulas Is Nothing Then
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            lngCalcMode = .Calculation
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        End With
        For Each rngCell In rngFormulas.Cells
            If LCase$(Left$(rngCell.Formula, 9)) <> "=iferror(" Then
                If rngCell.HasArray Then
                    With rngCell.CurrentArray
                        .FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(" & Mid$(.FormulaArray, 2) & ",0)"
                    End With
                Else
                    With rngCell
                        .Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid$(.Formula, 2) & ",0)"
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next rngCell
        With Application
            .Calculation = lngCalcMode
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```